# How to customize a ribbon bar to open forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016, ribbonx

I'm getting started with access 2016 and I wanted to add to the ribbon bar a tab that allow me to open my forms.

I tried to add it using ribbon bar customization in the options menu field but i cannot add my forms.

I also find that you can add a xml by creating a table called USysRibbons but I don't know the code to open add forms.

Can you help me showing me the correct way to customize the ribbon bar to add forms by using the default options or if I have to do it using an xml in the table can you show me an example of an xml file that opens a form in the ribbon bar please?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I use this site to get started with ribbon customizations https://www.accessribbon.de/en/

Comment: You want a tab on ribbon that lists forms? How - each form will have a button on that tab? This will probably involve xml ribbon code as well as ribbon callback. Probably better off creating a menu form.

Comment: Tried to post link to relevant page from Avenius site but it isn't working here. From the link in Ricardo's comment, click `Ribbon Callbacks > Button Callbacks > onAction`. Your VBA callback code could use `DoCmd.OpenForm "your form name here"`.